# How to show regional characters in Android

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I get a sites source code by Java and assign it to a string. But when i see content of that string there ara ? instead of ç,ş,İ,ğ. Hope you can help me.

Comment: People arent going to debug your code for you. Maybe you can narrow it down to a line that isn't working?

Comment: i add all code because maybe i am doing mistake when i getting html code.

Comment: Then maybe specify in your question where you think the problem is. Otherwise this might get closed because you're not asking a specific question

Comment: thanks for help i removed codes

Comment: That's not what I said. I said don't code dump and ask for debugging. Now nobody can answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataInputStream.readLine` is capable of reading latin1-encoded text only. The characters you want are not in latin1 so the page must have some different encoding, such as UTF-8.

Assuming the page is encoded in UTF-8 you can read it if you substitute the part where you declare and initialize the variable `in` with the following:

```
 Reader in = null;
 try {
 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

If you don't know the page encoding beforehand you may be able to use the [`URLConnection.getContentEncoding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentEncoding%28%29) method to find out. This method returns the encoding declared i the HTTP header `Content-Type`. If the content type does not have the encoding you just have to guess.

Comment: Wouldn't work here. The readUTF method assumes the first two bytes encode the string length.